# How to print only form.blade.php in Laravel dompdf

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf

I want to export/print only a form in PDF. 
This is the entire form

and I want to print just the those inside the box.

the main form is app.blade.php and it includes the side panel,header and the mid content(the data inside the red "box")

[image]
this is the code I've done so far:

```
 public function exportToPDF($projectID){

        $project = Project::find($projectID);
        $users = $project->users;
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('admin.projects.more', compact('project','users'));
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');

    }
```

it shows no error and downloads the file, but it is like this:
[image]

I don't understand why it even gets all the other stuff, when I've declared only projects.more

any idea?

Comment: why so few people have seen this? only 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use Inline CSS ,I have same issue Dompdf doesn't support external css**